# web app, jsp, and multithreaded

Tags: multithreading, jsp, web-applications, multi-user

I'm currently building a new web app, in Java EE with Apache Tomcat as a webserver.
I'm using jsps and servlets in my work.

my question is:

I have a very standard business logic. None of it is synchronized, will only a single thread of my web app logic will run at any given time?

Since making all functions "synchronized" will cause a huge overhead, is there any alternative for it?

If i have a static method in my project. that makes a very simple thing, such as:

```
       for (int i=0;i<10000;i++ ) {
           counter++;
       }
```

If the method is not thread safe, what is the behavior of such method in a multi user app? Is it unexpected behavior?!

and again in  a simple manner:

if i mean to build a multi user web app, should i "synchronize" everything in my project? if not all , than what should i sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will only a single thread of my web app logic will run at any given time?

No, the servlet container will create only one instance of each servlet and call that servlet's `doService()` method from multiple threads. In Tomcat by default you can expect up to 200 threads calling your servlet at the same time.

If the servlet was single-thread, your application would be slow like hell, see [`SingleThreadModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.html) - deprecated for a reason.

> making all function "synchronized" will make a huge overhead, is there any alternative for it?

There is - your code should be thread safe or better - stateless. Note that if your servlet does not have any state (like mutable fields - unusual), it can be safely accessed by multiple threads. The same applies to virtually all objects.

In your sample code with a `for` loop - this code is thread safe if `counter` is a local variable. It is unsafe if it is a field. Each thread has a local copy of the local variables while all threads accessing the same object access the same fields concurrently (and need synchronization).

> what should i sync?

Mutable, global, shared state. E.g. In your sample code if `counter` is a field and is modified from multiple threads, incrementing it must be synchronized (consider `AtomicInteger`).